# TextArea Input error: Request Failed Invalid Text value. A text field contains invalid data

Tags: jquery, html, dom, sharepoint-apps

My form contains a `textarea` input. When the user enters the data in this textarea and submits the form he is given the below error. Can any one help me in finding the problem and how can I solve this issue?

```
<textarea id="txt12" rows="14" cols="150" maxlength="80050"></textarea>
```

> Error: Request Failed Invalid Text value. A text field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again undefined

Comment: you have to put name attribute in your textarea ..and remove id and maxlength attribute till testing...

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea name="description" id="txt12" rows="14" cols="150" maxlength="80050"></textarea>
```

you're missing the name-attribute, Can you check

Comment: I am using ID attribute instead of name